# Как поставить счетчик комментариев hypercomments?

Tags: wordpress

Зарегистрировался у них на сайте, скачал плагин для вордпресс, все работает отлично, но никак не могу вывести счетчик комментариев на главную, чтобы показывалось кол-во комментариев каждого поста.

Вот код который я пытаюсь поставить

```
  <div id="hypercomments_mix"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
_hcwp = window._hcwp || [];
_hcwp.push({widget:"Bloggerstream", widget_id:68311, selector:"#post-<?php the_ID(); ?>,.post ", label:"{%COUNT%}"});
(function() {
if("HC_LOAD_INIT" in window)return;
HC_LOAD_INIT = true;
var lang = (navigator.language || navigator.systemLanguage || navigator.userLanguage ||  "en").substr(0, 2).toLowerCase();
var hcc = document.createElement("script"); hcc.type = "text/javascript"; hcc.async = true;
hcc.src = ("https:" == document.location.protocol ? "https" : "http")+"://w.hypercomments.com/widget/hc/68311/"+lang+"/widget.js";
var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(hcc, s.nextSibling);
})();
</script>
```

Может кто сталкивался со счетчиками на вордпресс?